# Deployment URL for JRebel with JBoss using CLI (no exploded war)?

Tags: maven, configuration, jboss, jrebel

I'm having trouble understanding how to configure the Deployment URL for JRebel for JBoss, when our application is not deployed as an exploded war, but via a Maven deploy using JBoss's CLI features.

In the properties window for JRebel (in Eclipse) what is required in the Deployment URL? Generally it's something like `http://my.server:1234/my-application.` However if we have no such directory then how is configuration done? is it even possible?

Deployment URL requires an address in the format:

> Deployment URL: http://serveraddress:port/???

Comment: Also I notice that JRebel is caching the files correctly in the /opt/jboss/.jrebel/cache/ directory. Still not sure what to put in the eclipse config

Answer (score 1):

You only need to use the JRebel remoting functionality (adding the deployment URL) if you're deploying your application onto a server that is on a different machine or VM than your IDE.

If you start JBoss from the CLI on the same machine as your IDE, then you don't need the deployment URL and should turn off remoting. Just need the Java agent and rebel.xml files.

Answer (score 0):

JRebel remoting Deployment URL is your application home page URL. JRebel will start listening on that server on a specific path that IDE knows to send the changed files over HTTP POST requests.

It is also possible to make JRebel listen to these HTTP request on custom port if needed. JVM argument -Drebel.remoting_port=[portNumber] will make this happen.